# What it means by unknown in truth table?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

This is a question that I encountered recently and am trying to understand.

I have an expression (P ∨ ~P) ∧ Q.

I have worked out the truth table and the last column of it is T, F, T, F.

Now, the question is asking for the truth value of (P ∨ ~P) ∧ Q with 3 options, "Unknown", "True" and "False".

Considering the last column of the truth table i T,F,T,F, I believe the answer is "Unknown"? Is it right to say that the answer will only be true or false if and only if the entire last column of the truth table is either true or false respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "unknown" means "depends on input", and you are right. An answer of "true" would mean "this expression is a tautology", i.e. returns true on all inputs, and likewise for "false" and the expression returning false on all inputs. Since both true and false values may be assumed by the given expression, the answer is "unknown".